# Jenkins on Docker. -- Hello World example Build fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am just started learning jenkins to create a simple pipeline. Weird that jenkins giving error on simple hello world example

I have installed docker based jenkins version and configured webaccess trying to create helloworld pipeline and tryied to build but its errorning like below. ( I have installed all recommended plugins) and on latest version of jenkins

```
    Started by user abadmin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 29: unable to resolve class edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings
 @ line 29, column 1.
   import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
```

any idea what is the reason. A simple example, all staright forward step but failing

I am using below pipeline code

```
    pipeline {
agent any
stages {
stage("Hello") {
steps {
echo 'Hello World'
}
}
}
}
```

any help will be apprecaited

Comment: Looks like a bad plugin installation.

Answer (score 0):

Update your jenkins to 2.190.3.  Remove your container, then rerun your create container script replacing the version number with the new version. This will upgrade your jenkins, your account and pipeline will still be there.